# Why is Canvas.drawPath() so slow?

Tags: android, performance, canvas

I encoutered that using Canvas.drawPath(path,paint) is significantly slower than Canvas.drawLine() in a row or using Canvas.drawLines() instead.
I can't give exact performance data, but I noticed on a Nexus 10 that the drawing was really slow (<10 FPS) by using path, while using drawLines was much smoother.
Is there some implementation wrong or maybe a parameter to speed up the performance of this?
As of now, I can't use drawPath() at all since the performance is such weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry cant leave a comment. drawPath() is making a lot more extra calls.  Path is an 
object and not an array.  Can you even imagine all of the extra calls 
that are made.  It is a Paint required method.  It is not good for 
fast multiple line drawing.  It is meant more for painting.

Answer (score 2):

I was having an issue with drawPath as well (especially on my Nexus 10). My issue came down to I was setting a

```
strokePaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(16f, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

which made the performance horrible. 45 milliseconds execution to for Canvas.drawPath. Once I removed it I was getting execution times between 2-4 milliseconds

Comment: Just witnessed the same issue, drawPath has a terrible performance with BlurMaskFilter. It's still the case today even on modern Android (API 28)!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call drawPath() more than once, you need to call path.reset() before you call drawPath()